# Getting "because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly" error when deserializing a Json object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Please help me. Where I am missing info?
I need to deserialize the following JSON string.

> {"results":[{"series":[{"name":"PWR_00000555","columns":["time","last"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",72]]}]}]}

For this, I have defined my class:

```
public class Serie
{
    public Serie()
    {
        this.Points = new List<object[]>();
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "results")]
    public string results { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "series")]
    public string sries { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "columns")]
    public string[] ColumnNames { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "values")]
    public List<object[]> Points { get; set; }
```

But when I try using the de-serializer, it gives an exception.

> {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[InfluxDB.Serie]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'results', line 2, position 12."}

Answer (score 20):

You are getting this error because your JSON is hierarchical while your class is essentially flat.  If you use [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate and reformat the JSON, you can see the structure better:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "series": [
                {
                    "name": "PWR_00000555",
                    "columns": [
                        "time",
                        "last"
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        [
                            "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                            72
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This corresponds to the following class structure (which I initially generated using [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/), then manually edited to add the `[JsonProperty]` attributes):

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("series")]
    public List<Series> Series { get; set; }
}

public class Series
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("columns")]
    public List<string> ColumnNames { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("values")]
    public List<List<object>> Points { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize your JSON into the above class structure like this:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/50Z64s

Comment: Really appreciated, I was struggling with a  hierarchical JSON, sample works perfectly for me!

Comment: Although the specifics of my situation are different from this question, this answer taught me EXACTLY the information I needed to figure out how to fix my own JSON objects in C# - thank you!

Answer (score 6):

If you're willing to sacrifice IntelliSense and compile time type safety, then you can simply deserialize the JSON into a dynamic object:

```
dynamic parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
PrintAllNames(parsed);

//...

private void PrintAllNames(dynamic obj)
{
    foreach(var result in obj.results)
        foreach(var item in result.series)
            Console.WriteLine(item.name);
}
```