# Getting Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException error when deserializing a Json object

Tags: json, api, json.net, docusignapi, serialization

I'm having an issue when trying to send [Docusign envelope](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/envelopes) with custom recipient mail (using recipientMailNotification) trough its API service. My controller receives the request properly, but before it sends to docusign service it deserializes into an object, and that's when the error occurs.

```
**JSON Request:**


"Recipients": [{
            "Order": 1,
            "Name": "Andre Test ",
            "Email": "andre@test.com",
            "SignerType": "SIGNER",
            "DocusignSignerType": 0,
            "SignatureType": "ELECTRONIC",
            "EtapaFinalizada": false,
            "EmailNotification":{
                "emailBody": "SIGN AS SIGNER",
                "emailSubject": "SIGNER SIGNATURE REQUIRED"
            }
        },
        {
            "Order": 2,
            "Name": "Luis Teste",
            "Email": "luis@test.com",
            "SignerType": "WITNESS",
            "DocusignSignerType": 0,
            "SignatureType": "ELECTRONIC",
            "EtapaFinalizada": false,
            "EmailNotification": {
                "emailBody": "SIGN AS WITNESS",
                "emailSubject": "WITNESS SIGNATURE REQUIRED"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Gives me the error:

```
'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object 
(e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[eSignature.
Providers.Docusign.Entities.RecipientEmailNotification]'
```

I'm not using a list<> or array of any type. is just a standard property nested inside another.

**Tried the solution listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427579/getting-because-the-type-requires-a-json-array-e-g-1-2-3-to-deserialize-co/59842970?noredirect=1#comment105824165_59842970) but still getting the error.**

Using Json2CSharp gives me same structure as my current class so I assume it is correct Json.

**EDIT: Please note that I'm not even expeting an array or List on my class property:**

```
public class Destinatario
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string SignerType{ get; set; }
    public int DocusignSignerType{ get; set; }
    public string SignatureType{ get; set; }
    public bool EtapaFinalizada { get; set; }
    public RecipientEmailNotification EmailNotification { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: are you using the DocuSign.eSign.dll nuget package? if so - what version?

Comment: @InbarGazit no. I'm using only eSign Rest API ver 2.1

Comment: ok, so you are using your own objects, so I can't really know what is the reason serialization fails. I would suggest you consider using the nuget, that won't have this issue.

Comment: one issue I see already - you need to change everything to a string. No int/bool etc. It's all strings.

Comment: can you please share your JSON which you used to generate your classes, also did you try your JSON to hit DS API directly via POSTMAN or any other REST API tool.

Comment: You *do* expect a list when deserializing the json, because you have an array of `Recipients`. Show us your deserialization call, the bug is there. Otherwise, it should work, see this fiddle [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QzT1od).

Comment: I agree with HeyJude's comment, to help you we would need to see a [mcve] that fully demonstrates the problem.  See: [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 0):

Recipients JSON looks like this:

```
"recipients": {
        "signers": [{
                "email": "test1@email.com",
                "name": "Name 1",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": *[{
                        "xPosition": "100",
                        "yPosition": "100",
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": "1"
                    }]
                }
            },
            {
                "email": "test2@email.com",
                "name": "Name 2",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "routingOrder": "2",
                "tabs": {
                    "initialHereTabs": *[{
                        "xPosition": "100",
                        "yPosition": "200",
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": "1"
                    }],
                    "signHereTabs": [*{
                        "xPosition": "200",
                        "yPosition": "200",
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": "1"
                    }]
                }
            }
        ],
        "carbonCopies": [{
                "email": "test3@email.com",
                "name": "Name 3",
                "recipientId": "3",
                "routingOrder": "3"
            },
            {
                "email": "test*4@email.com",
                "name": "Name 4",
                "recipientId": "4",
                "routingOrder": "3"
            }
        ]
    }
```

You do not have it separated into different kinds of recipients so your JSON is invalid.

Please see https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/recipients for more information.