# Not able to deserialize json using Newsoft.Json

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have JSON string, Its giving error when I am trying to deserialize it.

**JSON**:

```
[
    [
        {
            "fieldNameFK": 5
           
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "fieldNameFK": 6
            
        }
    ]
]
```

**Class**:

```
public class Root
{
    public List<List<Test>> Test{ get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
  
    public int FieldNameFK { get; set; }

}
```

**Code to deserialize**

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonStr);
```

**Exception**:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
> 'ConsoleApp1.Program+Root' because the type requires a JSON object
> (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error
> either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or
> change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a
> collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can
> be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be
> added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path
> '', line 1, position 1.

I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427579/getting-because-the-type-requires-a-json-array-e-g-1-2-3-to-deserialize-co) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557559/cannot-deserialize-the-json-array-e-g-1-2-3-into-type-because-type-requ) solution also, but It didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an json array at your root, not an json object so you need to deserialize to a collection, not object:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<Test>>>(jsonStr);
```

Comment: @viveknuna was glad to help!